# How do I change role settings in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

OK, by this, I dont mean the permissions, I mean this:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5wWl.png
I would like to use this to make a server template.

Thanks, bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `hoist`. You can change whether to hoist a role or not by using the `.setHoist()` method on a role. Let's say you're in a message event, you can do these things inside it to hoist a specific role:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    const yourRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'role-name'); // get the role using it's name, you can also find it using the id if you want to.
    yourRole.setHoist(true);  // setting hoist to true for this role
}
```

That's it. It will make the members who have this particular `yourRole` appear under a different category.

You can also specify whether to hoist a role or not when you are creating it using the `<RoleManager>.create()` method.